# Pre-selected rows with agGrid

Tags: ag-grid

Is there a way, when creating a new grid with agGrid to have some rows preselected? I mean, with the same effect as calling setSelected on them after creating the grid.

Maybe somehow in rowData when it's passed to agGrid?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to this problem is to have add one more column with values as 0 or 1 and then set row as selected in `rowDataChanged` and `modelUpdated` event.